# PyQt custom dialog -- how to get the return value?

Tags: python, pyqt

Using PyQt5, I'm trying to get a custom dialog (containing a simple QListWidget) to return a value.
I know similar questions have been asked before but somehow I don't seem to get the answers to work.

The custom dialog is in this class:

```
class ListSelection(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, item_ls, parent=None):
        super(ListSelection, self).__init__(parent)
        self.result = ""
        #================================================= 
        # listbox
        #================================================= 
        self.listWidget = QListWidget()
        for item in item_ls:
        w_item = QListWidgetItem(item)
        self.listWidget.addItem(w_item)
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.OnSingleC lick)
        self.listWidget.itemActivated.connect(self.OnDoubl eClick)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        row=0
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget,row,0,1,3) #col span=1, row span=3
        #================================================= 
        # OK, Cancel
        #================================================= 
        row +=1
        self.but_ok = QPushButton("OK")
        layout.addWidget(self.but_ok ,row,1)
        self.but_ok.clicked.connect(self.OnOk)

        self.but_cancel = QPushButton("Cancel")
        layout.addWidget(self.but_cancel ,row,2)
        self.but_cancel.clicked.connect(self.OnCancel)

        #================================================= 
        #
        #================================================= 
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 460, 350)

    def OnSingleClick(self, item):
        self.result = item.text()

    def OnDoubleClick(self, item):
        self.result = item.text()
        self.close()
        return self.result

    def OnOk(self):
        if self.result == "":
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Error",
            "One item must be selected")
            return 
        self.close()
        return self.result

    def OnCancel(self):
        self.close()

    def GetValue(self):
        return self.result
```

And this is what the calling function does:

```
def SomeFunction()
    ls = ['apples','bananas','melons']
    lb = ListSelection(ls)
    if lb.exec_():
        value = lb.GetValue()
        print(value)
```

The problem is, this does not capture any value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exec_` function does not return `True`, so you never print the value.

According to the documentation, it return a `QDialogCode`, an int. I tested with the code below, and it returns 0 (which evaluate to `False`)

```
def SomeFunction():
    ls = ['apples','bananas','melons']
    lb = ListSelection(ls)
    returnCode=lb.exec_()
    print(returnCode)
    value = lb.GetValue()
    print(value)
```

So just don't put an `if`, and it will print the value.

**Edit:**

I guess the correct behaviour would be to print the value if the user press Ok, and print nothing if the user press Cancel.

So instead of using `QDialog.close()`, you can use `QDialog.done(int)`, the integer being the `QDialogCode`. This way you can keep your `if` statement.

Comment: The OP wants to ignore the case where the user cancels. So the correct way to test is: `if lb.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted`.

Comment: Problem solved!  Also, using `QDialog.done(int)` instead of `QDialog.close()` is really an important tip.

Comment: @Karpov. Even better: use [`accept()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#accept) and [`reject()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#reject), rather than `close()`.